# convert DB2 column with varbinary datatype to equivalent in oracle

Tags: oracle, db2

I have column datatype on db2 as
**"column name" VARBINARY(2000) defalut Binary(X'20')**
I need its equivalent column datatype and default value for oracle

Comment: sql developer can help you with migrations and will define appropriate data types for your new oracle instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datatype replacement for VARBINARY is raw in oracle( as per remaining answers).
But the default value for Binary(X'20') is representing a space.
As the **hexadecimal** value for a **space is 20**,and for that reason its mentioned as **X'20'**.
**select rawtohex(' ') from dual;**  which will give you 20.

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle type RAW or LONG RAW , and use the same default value.

Example:

```
,mycol  raw(2000) default to_number(' ')
```

Comment: Before asking this question i know raw is the datatype in oracle but i am not sure about how to set default Binary(X'20') in oracle table creation script.    
could you please tell me what do you mean by "use the same default value"

Answer (score 1):

Use **RAW** or **LONG RAW** Datatype, However Oracle recommends **BLOB** and **BFILE** datatypes for large amounts of binary data.

Check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT613) for further information